# Windows media player missing in windows 8.1 single language

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-media-player

I recently bought a Lenovo Z50-70 laptop which was pre-loaded with **Windows 8.1 single user** OS. I wanted Windows Media Player and it was not found. I went through google and found that the 'N' versions of Windows 8.1 does not support Windows Media Player. But clearly my OS version is **Single User**.

I do not wish to spend any more just to have the old Windows 7 features back. Is there any direct link to download and use Windows Media Player?

Note : I do not need the latest version (I believe is WMP 12) of Media player. A previous working version would be okay.

Comment: check "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog in control panel->programs if the WMP is disabled here. If yes, activate it again.

Comment: Ohh yes I found it and it is working. I had checked it before but it was under media that I did not find. I really thank you so much. If you could add this as answer i could mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Media Player is already part of Windows. To install it, open the "[Turn Windows features on or off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-features-on-off#1TC=windows-7)" dialog in control panel->programs and set the checkbox to install it again.

[image]